# Parsing json messagepack data in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, json, websocket, messagepack

I'm sending json data to a websocketpp server with messagepack using kawanet/msgpack-lite (javascript) on the client and msgpack/msgpack-c (C++) to unpack it and nlohmann/json to parse it on the server. This goes fine.

But I'm apparently using messagepack the wrong way since I can't parse the returned data correctly.

Server:

```
if (jdata["type"] == "msg") {
    std::stringstream buffer;
    std::string clientmsg = jdata["data"];
    jdata["cnt"] = clientmsg.length();
    msgpack::pack(buffer, jdata.dump());
    size_t plen = buffer.tellp();
    msg->set_payload(&buffer, plen);
    m_server.send(hdl, msg);
}
```

Client:

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
    console.log("FileReader.onload(): " + reader.result);
    var decoded_message = msgpack.decode(reader.result);
}
reader.readAsText(e.data);
```

It fails on msgpack.decode() with

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid type: 0xh
```

When sending json as string in set_payload()

```
msg->set_payload(jdata.dump());
```

it's transmitted fine

```
FileReader.onload(): {"cnt":4,"data":"test","type":"msg"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The address of a `std::stringstream` is not a pointer to its underlying buffer.

Try: `msg->set_payload(buffer.str());`.

Comment: I tried that but it sends the data across in cleartext so it does not appear to be serialized.

Comment: that is because you are "packing" JSON strings. jdata.dump() serializes your data to a JSON string. msgpack::pack then packs this string. There isn't really much to pack. msgpack is generally something you would use instead of JSON, not to pack JSON.

Comment: Thank you. JSON is a nice format when working with javascript but may not be so ideal for C++. I have searched for ways to serialize data between javascript and C++ and messagepack looks like the preferred one. Maby I should look for a javascript library that mimics unordered_map in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps: nlohmann/json now supports MessagePack (and CBOR), so you now can realize your scenario completely withing nlohmann/json. See  https://github.com/nlohmann/json#binary-formats-cbor-and-messagepack for examples.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*